# Filter a haskell list

Tags: list, haskell

This is the code i have:

```
    data Review = Review {  artiest :: String,
                    score :: Integer,
                    tour :: Tour,
                    datum :: String,
                    plaats :: String,
                    soortLocatie :: Locatie,
                    topSongs :: [String]
                   } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

    getBestLoc [] beste = beste
    getBestLoc (x:xs) beste
        | (score x) > beste = getBestLoc xs (score x)
        | otherwise = getBestLoc xs beste
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the review whit the best score, but I want the Locatie to be returned. Now I get the best score returned. How can i solve this?

**EDIT**

So this is the new function I tried

```
    tester :: [Review] -> Locatie
    tester = loc
        where mxscr = maximumBy (compare `on` score)
      loc = map soortLocatie mxscr
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Function (on)

getBestLoc :: [Review] -> Review
getBestLoc = maximumBy (compare `on` score)
```

This function will return the `Review` with the highest score. After that, getting any field of the resulting review is trivial; your desired function would be `soortLocatie . getBestLoc`.

A brief explanation of what is going on: according to the docs, `on` follows the property:

```
g `on` f = \x y -> f x `g` f y
```

so

```
compare `on` score == \x y -> score x `compare` score y
```

In other words, it compares the two scores, return one of `LT, GT, EQ`. Then, `maximumBy` takes a comparison function and a list, and returns the maximum according to the comparison function. You can think of it as `maximum == maximumBy compare`.

Comment: This works, but now I get the full review where I only want the Locatie to be returned.

Comment: @brampieOO Then apply `soortLocatie` to the output of `getBestLoc`.

Comment: @Chris Taylor When I change Review to Locatie that doesn't work

Comment: @brampieOO Did you just change the type signature, or did you change the function definition too? Saying "that doesn't work" is not very informative. I think that you should read [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) to learn the basics of the language, rather than continuing to struggle.

Comment: @Chris Taylor I'm am using the website learn you a haskell bt english isn't my mother tongue so that sin't always that easy. under EDIT you find the new function I tried.

Comment: Note that `on compare  f` is the same as `comparing f`, where comparing is in `Data.Ord`

Comment: I wrote in my original answer that "your desired function would be `soortLocatie . getBestLoc` ". You don't need `map soortLocatie`, since the output is a single value.

Answer (score 1):

While user2407038 provides a perfectly correct answer, I want to provide a solution written slightly differently for clarity.

You want to return the `Locatie` of the `Review` with the best `score`. That means that all the other information in `Review` is immaterial for this process. We should drop it.

```
simplifyReview :: Review -> (Integer, Locatie)
simplifyReview r = (score r, soortLocatie r)
```

Now we simply want to return the pair which has the largest `fst` element and then we can get the second one. We'll use `maximumBy` to search a list of our simplified reviews

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)

getBestPair :: [(Integer, Locatie)] -> (Integer, Locatie)
getBestPair pairs = maximumBy comparePairs pairs where
  comparePairs (score1, locatie1) (score2, locatie2) = compare score1 score2
```

Finally we can combine these pieces to make the desired function

```
getBestLocatie :: [Review] -> Locatie
getBestLocatie reviews = snd (getBestPair (map simplifyReview reviews))
```

Often you'll see this written in "function composition form"

```
getBestLocatie :: [Review] -> Locatie
getBestLocatie = snd . getBestPair . map simplifyReview
```

Comment: a proper "decorate-sort-undecorate" pattern, esp. that computing the `score` might be a heavy operation.