# How to map a function in haskell with more than one parameter

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary

I have this function:

```
    aantalSong song list = let lijst = filterSong song list
        in teller lijst

    filterSong song list = filter (==song) list

    teller lijst = length lijst
```

And I wantto make something like this:

```
    aantalSongs song list revs = map (aantalSong song list) revs
```

If I'm right It isn't possible to do that, but what is the best alternative?

Comment: Your shown `aantalSongs` will also not typecheck.

Comment: In the future, please try to provide a [minimally complete example](http://sscce.org/) so that others can more quickly discern what your problem is.  Often, when distilling your example, you can even end up finding the solution to your problem by removing the "noise" that is unrelated portions of your program.  For Haskell in particular, try to always include type signatures, data declarations, and other relevant type information.  If you have some of this pre-defined in a past post, you can just link to it instead, but I would prefer seeing it all in one place =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aantalSong` effectively just counts how many times a particular song shows up in a list of songs. Assuming `revs` is something like a list of `Review`s (for future readers, see the previous question: [Filter a haskell list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677462/filter-a-haskell-list/20686218#20686218)) then you'll want to map the "song list getter" along with `aantalSong`.

```
aantalSongs song revs = map (\rev -> aantalSong song (topSongs rev)) revs
```

We can do a lot of tricks to compress this code and perhaps make it clearer. First some eta-reduction and movement to compositional style.

```
aantalSongs song revs = map (\rev -> aantalSong song (topSongs rev)) revs
aantalSongs song      = map (\rev -> aantalSong song (topSongs rev))
aantalSongs song      = map (aantalSong song . topSongs)
```

Then we break open `aantalSong` and see if we can simplify it further. This is essentially just a lot of function inlining.

```
aantalSong song list = let lijst = filterSong song list in teller lijst
aantalSong song list = let lijst = filterSong song list in length lijst
aantalSong song list = length (filterSong song list)
aantalSong song      = length . filterSong song
aantalSong song      = length . filter (== song)
```

Combining the pieces gives us a relatively simple form of this function.

```
-- | The number of times a particular song is 
-- given as the 'topSong' in each review.
aantalSongs :: String -> [Review] -> [Int]
aantalSongs song = map (length . filter (== song) . topSongs)
```

In my own code, I typically would write this as just

```
-- | The number of times a particular song is 
-- given as the 'topSong' in a review.
aantalSongs :: String -> Review -> Int
aantalSongs song = length . filter (== song) . topSongs
```

and `map` over lists of `Review` when needed.

Some people criticize point-free style as being obfuscating and "pointless", but used appropriately I think it makes for code that is quite wonderful to read.

Comment: Used like that point-free style is good, but if you then go ahead and make it truly point-free by eliminating the song argument it will be a totally incomprehensible.

Comment: @augustss As with almost any programming practice, there is a time and place for it, and an extreme limit that is rarely worth it.  I often shy away from the point free functions that are a mess of compositions and strange higher level functions, but I think the notation has serious benefits when used appropriately as Abrahamson has.

Comment: I don't have one song of which I need to know how many times it occurs. I have a list of songs of an artist. So how do I do that?

Comment: @augustss To be fair, my final paragraph was written exactly to curtail my own shoulder-demon egging me to pointfree out `song`. It's sometimes a fight to remember that you're optimizing for readability not point-count.

Comment: For the record, my mental model is usually to try to see pointfree as an expression of the "piping" nature of a computation if it exists. To my aesthetics here, `song` should not be de-pointed because it parameterizes the behavior of the pipe which converts `Review` to `Int`. That also is a hint that it should be an early argument so it can be more easily parameterized.

Comment: @brampieOO Try replacing the condition in `filter` (which is `(== song)` here) to something that checks to see if the song is part of a set. You might write `filter (\song -> elem song artistSongs)` perhaps.

Comment: @J. Abrahamson Thats not what I mean. I have a list (list1) with all the songs of an artist (some songs are in there two or more times). And I have a list (list2) with the songs of that same artist but every song is only one time in there. So i would like to check how many times the songs of list2 occur in list1. I hope this time I have my question right.

Comment: @brampieOO Ah! That's a bit more complex than I can explain in a comment, but I can fit it here. Try `map (\song -> (length $ filter (== song) list1, song)) list2`. It has the type `[String] -> [Int]`, but it's a bit slow because it reviews elements `length list1 * length list2` times. You can do better than that by only traversing `list1` once.

Comment: @brampieOO Using `Data.Map` we can build `counts :: Ord a => [a] -> Map a Int` which is pretty nice: `counts = foldr (\song -> Map.insertWith (+) song 1) Map.empty`. Then we have `let cs = counts list1 in map (\song -> Map.findWithDefault 0 song cs) list2`

Comment: Thank you, `map (\song -> (length $ filter (== song) list1, song)) list2` works perfect! The fact that it is slow doesn't mather because it aren't that big lists.